# Valuebox with a single date of a table

Tags: r, shiny

I am trying to do a valuebox in shiny using a single date of a table. My table looks like this:

```
Color<-c("blanco","blanco","gris","gris","blanco","gris","gris","gris","blanco","blanco","gris","blanco","gris","blanco","gris")
Tipo<-c("gato","gato","gato","perro","perro","perro","perro",
        "buho","buho","buho","buho","tigre","tigre","tigre","tigre")
data<-data.frame(Color,Tipo)
```

In my UI

```
   tabsetPanel(
       position= "left",
     tabPanel("Cancelaciones", icon = icon("window-close"),
                         fluidRow(
                            uiOutput("Box1")),
                        sidebarLayout(sidebarPanel(
                            uiOutput("SelectTipo")
                         ),
                         mainPanel( 
                            plotlyOutput("barplotx"),
                           dataTableOutput("summaryx")
                         ) ) )
                ))
```

Server

```
  output$SelectTipo<-renderUI({
   selectInput("SelectTipo", "Tipo",
            data$Tipo, multiple = T, selected = TRUE) 
  })

df<-reactive({
data %>%
  filter(Tipo %in% input$SelectTipo)
  })  

df1<-reactive({
df2<-df()
df2 %>%
count(Color)%>%
mutate(percent=round(((n/sum(n))*100), digits=2))%>%
arrange(desc(percent))>tmpx
names(tmpx)<- c("Evento","N","Porcentaje")
tmpx


  })
   valor<-df1[1,2] ##### <-----here is the line
 output$Box1 <- renderUI({ 
 valueBox(value = valor(), subtitle = "Valor", ##### <-and here
  icon = icon("check-circle"),
  color = "green")  
 })
```

I want the value box to be the value in column 1, row 2.

Comment: I suggest you first reformat your code. And I noticed that you are trying to use `df1` inside that own reactive, which isn't going to output anything. If you can define that `df1` reactive then you can do `return(valor)`. You should not use valor() as it stands inside the `valueBox`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can subset the dataframe to get the required value.

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)

ui <- fluidPage({
  uiOutput('Box1')
})

server <- function(input, output) {
  
  valor <- reactive(data)

  output$Box1 <- renderUI({ 
    valueBox(value = valor()[2, 1], #2nd row, 1st column
             subtitle = "Valor", 
             icon = icon("check-circle"),
             color = "green")  
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

[image]